# How to calculate minimum number of zeros of a polynomial using Rolle's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

**Q)** If f(x) is a twice differentiable function such that $f(a) = 0, f(b) = 2, f(c) = -1, f(d) = 2, f(e) = 0$ where $a<b<c<d<e$ then the minimum number of zeros of $g(x) = (f'(x))^2 + f''(x)f(x)$ in the interval $[a,e]$ is -

I am trying to solve this question using Rolle's Theorem. I identified that $g(x)$ is the first derivative of the function on which I have to apply Rolle's Theorem.

$g(x) = (f'(x))^2 + f''(x)f(x) = p'(x)$

$\therefore p(x) = f(x)f'(x)$

I am stuck here. I don't understand how to proceed from here. I'll be deeply grateful to any help received. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, the question is not stated very nicely. The minimum number of zeros is $0$. But to be a bit helpful: Since $p(a)=p(e)=0$ we can definetly expect one zero.

Comment: The answer is 6. And this question is all I've got. I haven't framed it myself. There is no fault in the question

Comment: Note p(x) = 0 when f or f' = 0. f is 0 at a, at e, somewhere between c and d, and somewhere between b and c. f' is 0 somewhere from a to c, somewhere from b to d, and somewhere from c to e. There's some overlapping ranges, but I'm guessing you end up showing there are 7 locations where p(x) = 0, so there are at least 6 zeros to g.

Comment: expanding on the previous comment. There are at least 4 places where f is 0. Thus there are at least 3 places where f' is 0 (by rolles). Thus there are at least 7 places where p is 0, so there are at least 6 places where g is 0.

Comment: But Rolle's Theorem says that we're supposed to check for the zeros of the first derivative of the function. Then why are we checking when p(x) is becoming zero ? Don't we have to check when p(a) = p(e) ? And that happens only at 2 places. Hence, only one root. I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: But between $x = b$ and $x = c$, the function is crossing $x$-axis. Similarly it again crosses x-axis between $x = c$ and $d$. So you should have at least $3$ points where $f' = 0$. If you now consider points between $b$ and $c$, there should be two points where the expression is zero, one to the left of the point where $f' = 0$ and one to the right. Similarly two points between $c$ and $d$, and two points between $d$ and $e$.

Comment: Ohhh alright. I think I sort of misinterpreted Rolle's Theorem. It's clear now. Thank you everyone!